# HTML5 required fields in Chrome

Tags: html, validation, google-chrome

I have some required="required" input fields in my form. It works nicely in Firefox, but in Chrome it does not pop any errors when fields are empty, but still prevents form submission, which is not very user-friendly. I know this use to work in older versions of Chrome.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="contact-form" action="/kontakt">
                <div id="sylius_core_contact"><div class="form-field"><label for="sylius_core_contact_name" class=" required control-label">
    Ime i prezime
    </label><br><input type="text" id="sylius_core_contact_name" name="sylius_core_contact[name]" required="required"></div><div class="form-field"><label for="sylius_core_contact_email" class=" required control-label">
    Adresa e-pošte
    </label><br><input type="email" id="sylius_core_contact_email" name="sylius_core_contact[email]" required="required"></div><div class="form-field"><label for="sylius_core_contact_message" class=" required control-label">
    Poruka
    </label><br><textarea id="sylius_core_contact_message" name="sylius_core_contact[message]" required="required" rows="9"></textarea></div><input type="hidden" id="sylius_core_contact__token" name="sylius_core_contact[_token]" value="dc6f7bf332ad26f1cd9ae0aeba51f3ab4704578e"></div>
                <input value="Pošalji poruku" class="green-button" type="submit">
            </form>
```

What is wrong with new Chrome?

Comment: That attribute should trigger client side validation in HTML5 browsers. Which it does, but for some reason in new versions of Chrome it does not report validation errors, just prevents form submit.

Comment: It would help if you shared your code with us.

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact behvior on some fields in the latest Chrome (v.75) in July 2019.  Works fine in Safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Chromium https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45804.